# How to make rule trigger on DNS rdata/IP address?

Tags: domain-name-system, snort

I currently have the following DNS Query Alert rule set up in Suricata (for test purposes):

```
 alert dns any any -> any any (msg:”Test dns_query option”; dns_query; content:”google”; nocase; sid:1;)
```

Which is triggered when it captures DNS events which contain the word "google", such as in this packet:

```
{"timestamp":"2017-06-08T15:58:59.907085+0000","flow_id":1798294020028434,"in_iface":"ens33","event_type":"dns","src_ip":"172.16.10.132","src_port":53,"dest_ip":"192.168.160.140","dest_port":52385,"proto":"UDP","dns":{"type":"answer","id":57334,"rcode":"NOERROR","rrname":"www.google.com","rrtype":"A","ttl":300,"rdata":"172.217.12.164"}}
```

However, instead of searching for resource record names that contain "google", I want to use this same kind of alert to trigger on IP addresses that resolve to loopback, as is the case with the following packet (Notice the `rdata` field):

```
{"timestamp":"2017-06-08T15:59:37.120927+0000","flow_id":36683121284050,"in_iface":"ens33","event_type":"dns","src_ip":"172.16.10.132","src_port":53,"dest_ip":"192.168.160.140","dest_port":62260,"proto":"UDP","dns":{"type":"answer","id":53553,"rcode":"NOERROR","rrname":"outlook1.us","rrtype":"A","ttl":120,"rdata":"127.0.0.1"}}
```

As I have noticed, the `content`section of a Suricata rule searches only for a string.
My current rule triggers on a text match with the rrname/domain, how would I make it so that the rule triggers on rdata/IP address?

p.s.
Just out of curiosity I tried replacing the "google" in the content section of my alert with "127.0.0.1" and that didn't work either, as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ip address is just a 32 bit number. In the rule the IP should be represented as a hex value and not a string, for purposes of efficiency and saving bandwidth (a string will be 8+ bytes as opposed to 4 bytes).

Here is my final Suricata rule to alert whenever somebody gets sent to loopback on my network:

```
alert dns any any -> any any (msg:"BLACKLISTED DOMAIN"; content:"|7F 00 00 01|"; sid:1;)
```